# Is there a way to access slots in the superclass list in CLOS?

Tags: common-lisp, clos, mop

Is there a way to access slots of superclasses in CLOS?

E.g., in Objective C I can perform

```
- (void) frob {
[super frob]
}
```

This sends a message to the (sole) superclass of frob.

Perusing the CLOS documentation suggests that `DEFCLASS` merges all superclass information on class creation and thus this ability to communicate with the superclass is lost. Is this correct?

edit:

The scenario is somewhat unusual:

Given classes

```
(defclass animal ()
  ((behavior-types
     :initform '(:eat :sleep :drink)
     :reader behavior-types)))

(defclass cow (animal)  
  ((behavior-types
     :initform '(:moo :make-milk)
     :reader behavior-types))

(defclass horse
  ((behavior-types 
     :initform '(:buck :gambol :neigh)
     :reader behavior-types))
```

How to have a method, say, `BEHAVIOR-TYPES` or `GET-BEHAVIOR` that, when called with an object of type `horse`, returns `'(:eat :sleep :drink :buck :gambol :neigh)`.  That is to say, inheritance via a slot "adds" to the initform rather than replaces it.

An easy solution is, rather than to assign the data to the class, to have a generic method like so:

```
(defgeneric behavior-types (obj))

(defmethod behavior-types ((obj animal)) nil)

(defmethod behavior-types :around ((obj animal))
  (append '(:eat :sleep :drink)
          (call-next-method obj)))


(defmethod behavior-types :around ((obj horse))
  (append '(:gambol :neigh :buck)
          (call-next-method obj)))
```

However, this solution moves the data into the `defgeneric` rather than the class, where it properly belongs.  So the motivation for the question came forth out of this.

At any rate - the question as asked reflected a misunderstanding of CLOS's design. It is not possible, as asked and within the *normal* framework, to perform this task. However, two separate approaches are given below using the MOP to solve the problem I posed.

Comment: Based on your comment to my answer, "I am not terribly interested in calling a method, I'm looking at accessing a slot", it's not exactly clear to me what you're trying to do and what's not working about it. All the accessors/readers/writers specialized for the superclass will still work with the subclass, as should [`slot-value`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_slt_va.htm).  What are you trying to do that's producing unexpected results?

Comment: I have two classes, C1, C2. The slot is initform'd in C1 and in C2. C2's slot "adds" to C1's information (rather than strictly overrides it). I would like the reader for C2's slot to use both C1's slot and C2's slot to produce the result.

Comment: There's only _one_ slot in the instance of C2, but as you say, some of the information that defines it may be in the specification of C1.  However, the _readers_ (and writers, and accessors) that `defclass` defines are methods, so you can still do specialized things with them.  Can you give a specific example of what you'd like the reader that's specialized for C2 to do?  With a specific example, it sounds like it might not be too hard to implement.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: The truth is, I can (and did) hack an interface together with `(DEFMETHOD FOO :around ...)` . I was probing about cleaner approaches that stored the data in the actual data structure rather than in the DEFMETHOD.  Loosely, what I'm trying to do is have behavior for AI agents that "broadens" as they get further down the inheritance tree. Each class of agent has behaviors that include its parents as well as its (the classes) own behaviors. The interface to read them should be BEHAVIOR. Instances of the class might *also* have their own behaviors added to the class list behaviors.

Comment: My limited understanding is that slots are initialized while calling `initialize-instance`, so if you want to initialize them, by first executing the superclass' initform and then appending to it the initform of the current class, I'd look into MOP: http://www.alu.org/mop/dictionary.html#Initialization this seems to be the relevant place. My course of action would be: 1) figure who's the superclass, 2) fetch the slot definition, 3) execute initform from there (possibly recursively), 4) execute present initform and append to the previous result.

Comment: actually, I think you need this: http://www.alu.org/mop/dictionary.html#compute-effective-slot-definition it should give you the slot definitions of the superclasses before the slot is initialized, so you could combine the superclass initforms with the current one in some way. I'm going to try to make an example.

Comment: @wvxvw: Interesting. My MOP-fu is weak (I rarely go into the MOP). I've read those paragraphs a few times in the last few days and didn't connect it to a possible solution. I am interested in your approach.

Comment: [This post](http://www.xach.com/lisp/allegro-cl/1998-9/666.html) may be very close to what you're looking for.

Comment: @PaulNathan I've updated my answer with a bit about the MOP that was described, and I'm going to update with a more (guaranteed to be) portable, but slightly less automatic approach using CLOS method combinations, too.

Comment: Just a reminder to award answers if they are satisfactory such as the two given.

Comment: @ghollisjr : Yes, I know. The actual answer to the question is "No". But it's possible to metaprogram to make the system do what I want. /not sure which to pick.

Answer (score 5):

The title of your question makes it sound like you're asking about how to access slots, but the code you show seems more like it's about calling methods that have been specialized for the superclass.  If it's the latter that you're looking for, you should take a look at [`call-next-method`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_call_n.htm), as well as [7.6 Generic Functions and Methods](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/07_f.htm) from the HyperSpec.

### Calling “superclass methods”

In CLOS, methods don't *belong* to classes like they do in some other languages.   Instead, there are generic functions on which specialized methods are defined.  For a given argument list, a number of methods may be applicable, but only one is *most specific*.  You can call the next most specific method with `call-next-method`.  In the following transcript, there's a class `FOO` and a subclass `BAR`, and a generic function `FROB` which has methods specialized for `FOO` and `BAR`.  In the method specialized for `BAR`, there's a call to `call-next-method` which, in this case, calls the method specialized for `FOO`.

```
CL-USER> (defclass foo () ())
;=> #<STANDARD-CLASS FOO>
CL-USER> (defclass bar (foo) ())
;=> #<STANDARD-CLASS BAR>
CL-USER> (defgeneric frob (thing))
;=> #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION FROB (0)>
CL-USER> (defmethod frob ((foo foo))
           (print 'frobbing-a-foo))
;=> #<STANDARD-METHOD FROB (FOO) {1002DA1E11}>
CL-USER> (defmethod frob ((bar bar))
           (call-next-method)
           (print 'frobbing-a-bar))
;=> #<STANDARD-METHOD FROB (BAR) {1002AA9C91}>
CL-USER> (frob (make-instance 'bar))

FROBBING-A-FOO 
FROBBING-A-BAR 
;=> FROBBING-A-BAR
```

### Simulating it with method combinations

You can use method combinations to combine the results of the methods that are applicable to a list of arguments.  For instance, you can define a method `a` with the method combination `list` that means when you call `(a thing)`, *all* the methods on `a` applicable for the argument are called, and their results are combined into a list.  If you give your slots in the different classes different names, and specialize methods on `a` that read those values, you can simulate the sort of thing you're looking for.  This doens't prevent you from also using a traditional reader that accesses the slot, as well (e.g., `get-a` in the following example). The following code shows an example:

```
(defgeneric a (thing)
  (:method-combination list))

(defclass animal ()
  ((animal-a :initform 'a :reader get-a)))

(defmethod a list ((thing animal))
  (slot-value thing 'animal-a))

(defclass dog (animal)
  ((dog-a :initform 'b :reader get-a)))

(defmethod a list ((thing dog))
  (slot-value thing 'dog-a))

(a (make-instance 'dog))

(get-a (make-instance 'animal))
;=> A

(get-a (make-instance 'dog))
;=> B
```

### Using the MOP

[This post](http://www.xach.com/lisp/allegro-cl/1998-9/666.html) from 1998 on Allegro CL archives is worth a read.  It sounds like the author is looking for something similar to what you're looking for.

> I need to define an inheritance behavior that concatenates
>   string-values of superclass-initforms with local slot initforms. E.g.
>
> ```
> (defclass super()
>   ((f :accessor f :initform "head")) (:metaclass user-class))
>
> (defclass sub(super)
>   ((f :accessor f :initform "tail")) (:metaclass user-class))
> ```
>
> I'd like to get the following:
>
> ```
> (f(make-instance'sub)) -> "head tail"
> ```
>
> I didn't find a standard option in defclass slot-descriptions for
>   this. I'd like to define the concatenate combination for each
>   meta-class 'user-class'.

The response (by Heiko Kirschke, not me, but also see [this response from Jon White](http://www.xach.com/lisp/allegro-cl/1998-9/669.html) with a similar approach), defines a new type of class:

```
(defclass user-class (standard-class) ())
```

and specializes `clos:compute-effective-slot-definition` to provide an initform that's computed from the slot definitions of the class and its superclass(es):

```
(defmethod clos:compute-effective-slot-definition
    ((the-class user-class) slot-name
     ;; The order of the direct slots in direct-slot-definitions may
     ;; be reversed in other LISPs (this is code written & tested with
     ;; ACL 4.3):
     direct-slot-definitions)
  (let ((slot-definition (call-next-method))
    (new-initform nil))
    (loop for slot in direct-slot-definitions
    as initform = (clos:slot-definition-initform slot)
    when (stringp initform)
    do
      ;; Collecting the result string could be done perhaps more
      ;; elegant:
      (setf new-initform (if new-initform
                 (concatenate 'string initform " "
                          new-initform)
                   initform)))
    (when new-initform
      ;; Since at (call-next-method) both the initform and
      ;; initfunction of the effective-slot had been set, both must be
      ;; changed here, too:
      (setf (slot-value slot-definition 'clos::initform) new-initform)
      (setf (slot-value slot-definition 'clos::initfunction)
    (constantly new-initform)))
    slot-definition))
```

Then it's used like this:

```
(defclass super ()
  ((f :accessor f :initform "head"))
  (:metaclass user-class))

(defclass sub(super)
  ((f :accessor f :initform "tail"))
  (:metaclass user-class))

(f (make-instance 'sub))
==> "head tail"
```

This is getting into MOP functionality that's not specified by the spec, so you might have to adapt it for your particular implementation.   There are some MOP compatibility layer packages out there that might be able to help you out, though.

Comment: I am not terribly interested in calling a `method`, I'm looking at accessing a `slot`.

Comment: @PaulNathan OK, I thought that the Objective-C code was along the lines of method invocation, rather than slot access.  So, what is it that doesn't work?  The slot-accessor/reader/writer functions should all still work, as should `slot-value`…

Answer (score 3):

There is no such concept as the instance slot of a superclass in CLOS.

If you create an instance, it has all slots. All slots from the class and its superclasses.

If a class has a slot `FOO` and some superclasses have also slots named `FOO`, all those are merged into one slot. Each instance of that CLOS class will have that slot.

Still you need to be more careful with your wording. Superclasses are objects themselves and they have slots themselves. But this has nothing to do with an instance having local slots and having superclasses with instance slots. The latter does not exist in CLOS.

```
CL-USER 18 > (defclass bar () (a b))
#<STANDARD-CLASS BAR 413039BD0B>
```

Above is then a superclass with two slots.

```
CL-USER 19 > (defclass foo (bar) (b c))
#<STANDARD-CLASS FOO 4130387C93>
```

Above is a class with two local and one inherited slot. The slot `b` is actually merged from this class and from the superclass.

```
CL-USER 20 > (describe (make-instance 'foo))

#<FOO 402000951B> is a FOO
B      #<unbound slot>
C      #<unbound slot>
A      #<unbound slot>
```

Above shows that the instance has three slots and all can be directly accessed. Even the slot `a, which was defined in the superclass.

If we look at the actual superclass as an instance itself, we see its slots:

```
CL-USER 21 > (describe (find-class 'bar))

#<STANDARD-CLASS BAR 413039BD0B> is a STANDARD-CLASS
NAME                         BAR
DEFAULT-INITARGS             NIL
DIRECT-DEFAULT-INITARGS      NIL
DIRECT-SLOTS                 (#<STANDARD-DIRECT-SLOT-DEFINITION A 4020005A23> #<STANDARD-DIRECT-SLOT-DEFINITION B 4020005A93>)
DIRECT-SUBCLASSES            (#<STANDARD-CLASS FOO 4130387C93>)
DIRECT-SUPERCLASSES          (#<STANDARD-CLASS STANDARD-OBJECT 40F017732B>)
PRECEDENCE-LIST              (#<STANDARD-CLASS BAR 413039BD0B> #<STANDARD-CLASS STANDARD-OBJECT 40F017732B> #<BUILT-IN-CLASS T 40F00394DB>)
PROTOTYPE                    NIL
DIRECT-METHODS               NIL
WRAPPER                      #(1539 (A B) NIL #<STANDARD-CLASS BAR 413039BD0B> (#<STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION A 4020005AFB> #<STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION B 4020005B63>) 2)
LOCK                         #<MP::SHARING-LOCK "Lock for (STANDARD-CLASS BAR)" Unlocked 41303AD4E3>
DOCUMENTATION-SLOT           NIL
PLIST                        (CLOS::COPYABLE-INSTANCE #<BAR 402000638B>)
POTENTIAL-INITARGS           0
MAKE-INSTANCE-FLAGS          509
OTHER-LOCK                   #<MP:LOCK "Lock for (OTHER STANDARD-CLASS BAR)" Unlocked 41303AD553>
REINITIALIZE-INITARGS        0
REDEFINE-INITARGS            0
DEPENDENTS                   NIL
```

Comment: Imprecision in understanding yields imprecision of wording. :-)  Nevertheless, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is really, really hasckish. I hope someone will step in and fix it, though it should illustrate the idea:

```
(defclass agent () ((behaviour :initform do-nothing :accessor behaviour-of)))

(defclass walk-agent (agent) ((behaviour :initform and-walk)))

(defclass talk-agent (walk-agent) ((behaviour :initform and-talk)))

(defmethod sb-mop:compute-effective-slot-definition
           :after (class (name (eql 'behaviour)) sdlotds)
  (setf *slot-def* 
        (loop
           :for slot :in sdlotds :do
           (format t "~&slot: ~s" (sb-mop:slot-definition-initform slot))
           :collect (sb-mop:slot-definition-initform slot))))

(defmethod initialize-instance :before ((instance agent) &rest keyargs)
  (declare (ignore keyargs))
  (let (*slot-def*)
    (declare (special *slot-def*))
    (sb-mop:compute-slots (class-of instance))
    (setf (behaviour-of instance) *slot-def*)))

;; (behaviour-of (make-instance 'talk-agent))

;; slot: AND-TALK
;; slot: AND-WALK
;; slot: DO-NOTHING
;; slot: AND-TALK
;; slot: AND-WALK
;; slot: DO-NOTHING
;; (AND-TALK AND-WALK DO-NOTHING)
```

PS. I see that the function that computes the list of slots definitions in SBCL is in std-class.lisp, `std-compute-slots`. So it isn't something that MOP defines in some way... But this one would be really helpful here.

Comment: Interesting. FYI, this seems to work using CLOSER-MOP.   I think this is what I'm looking for, or at least very close. I started with using :class allocation, since the behavior is common to all members of the class. However, CLOS appears to merge the slot information. Using this approach with :class, allocation becomes sort of a mix between :class and :instance allocation. It solves a certain class of problem I've had for a long time - how to retain behavior based on self and superclasses, as well as modify it for instances of class. Do you mind if I write this up on my blog?

Comment: @PaulNathan not at all, but I'd wait for someone more knowledgeable to comment. I really don't like to collect slot info in this way. Technically, one could copy the code from `std-compute-slots` to avoid quite a bit of redundant stuff going on here, but maybe there's even a better way to do it.

Comment: Tangentially, what I'm actually groping towards is a variance of behavior from the usual OO storage/inheritance rules. It's possible that the appropriate mechanism is to use the MOP and have a metaclass. It's also possible that what I'm trying to do is simply outside the possible paradigm... maybe I should find a OO guru and ask them.

Comment: @PaulNathan that would be a problem pretty much in every language: you'd need to code around it in constructor function or similar, the value of the field of the superclass is usually not in the scope where you need to define the value for the subclass field. In many other languages you have to write constructor function explicitly, but in Lisp it is usually trivial and is generated automatically, that's why it looks like there's a difference.